# Como posso fazer dois gráficos num mesmo plot em Python no Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, plot, graphics, anaconda

Eu estou a tentar criar gráficos no Jupyter Notebook em Python pela primeira vez usando dados de um ficheiro excel para a minha Tese de Mestrado, porque eu não quero apresentar os gráficos em Excel e quero fazer algo mais profissional.

Até agora consegui criar dois gráficos em separado, mas o que eu queria obter eram dois gráficos no mesmo plot com a mesma legenda, título de eixos, título do gráfico, grelha e não estou a conseguir.

Alguém me poderia dizer, por favor, como posso melhorar o gráfico e colocar os dois gráficos no mesmo plot?

Ficheiro Excel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None, usecols=[0,1,2,3], names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
plt.style.use('classic')
X = df['A']
Y = df['B']
x_list = list(X)
y_tuple = tuple(Y)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10.5,9]
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=16)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=14)
plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = "w"
df.plot(x='A', y='B', label='Perfil de temperatura do forno', linestyle='--', marker='o', 
color='blue', markersize=4)
x1 = df['A']
y1 = df['D']
x1_list = list(x1)
y1_list = list(y1)
df.plot(x='A', y='D', label='Perfil de temperatura do forno', linestyle='--', marker='o', 
color='red', markersize=4)
#plt.grid(b=True, color='black', alpha=0.3, linestyle='-.', linewidth=1) #caso quisesse a 
grid completa e nao apenas a horizontal
axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid(b=True, color='black', alpha=0.3, linestyle='-.', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('Tempo (minuto)', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Temperatura (ºC)', fontsize=15)
plt.title('Perfil de temperatura do forno')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar o gráfico dessa forma:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_excel

df = read_excel('./carmen.xlsx', names = ['A','B','C','D'])
```

Definindo o que será plotado:

```
plt.plot(df['A'], df['B'], linestyle='--', marker='o', color = 'blue', markersize = 4)
plt.plot(df['A'], df['D'], linestyle='--', marker='o', color = 'red', markersize = 4)
```

Definindo os labels x e y:

```
plt.xlabel('Tempo(minuto)', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Temperatura °C', fontsize=15)
```

Definindo o título do gráfico:

```
plt.title('Perfil de temperatura do forno')
```

Definindo a legenda:

```
plt.legend(['Perfil de temperatura do forno','Perfil de temperatura do forno'], fontsize=14)
```

Obtendo a instancia atual dos eixos

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid(b=True, color='black', alpha=0.3, linestyle='-.', linewidth=1)
```

Definindo o tamanho da figura:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10.5, 9))
```

Mostrando o gráfico:

```
plt.show()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*O gráfico vai diferenciar do seu pois eu não tenho todos os dados, só tenho até a linha 31 do seu arquivo excel.*

Comment: Muito obrigada pela explicação detalhada. Percebi bastante bem o que quis dizer

Comment: Por nada Carmen, que bom que a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Abraços!